# HTTP 500: Internal Server Error - No such profile : Jupyterhub on GKE

Tags: google-cloud-platform, jupyter-notebook, google-kubernetes-engine, jupyterhub

I am trying to install a Jupyterhub on GKE cluster

By following steps mentioned in below

[github.com
GoogleCloudPlatform/ai-notebooks-extended
main/gke-hub-example](https://github.com%20GoogleCloudPlatform/ai-notebooks-extended%20main/gke-hub-example)

JupyterHub got sucesfully installed, but when i try to start a Notebook instance , it throws the below error

`Error: HTTP 500: Internal Server Error (Error in Authenticator.pre_spawn_start: ValueError No such profile: [‘gcr-io-noted-amphora-248618-jupyter-mine-basic’]. Options include: gcr-io-noted-amphora-248618-jupyter-mine-basic, gcr-io-noted-amphora-248618-jupyter-mine-basic)`

Below are the log messages

```
2021-06-02T10:06:39.620382674Z Watches established. E
2021-06-02T10:06:41.466552969Z [I 2021-06-02 10:06:41.466 JupyterHub app:2332] Running JupyterHub version 1.2.2 E
2021-06-02T10:06:41.466680449Z [I 2021-06-02 10:06:41.466 JupyterHub app:2362] Using Authenticator: gcpproxiesauthenticator.gcpproxiesauthenticator.GCPProxiesAuthenticator E
2021-06-02T10:06:41.466780251Z [I 2021-06-02 10:06:41.466 JupyterHub app:2362] Using Spawner: kubespawner.spawner.KubeSpawner-1.0.0 E
2021-06-02T10:06:41.466891898Z [I 2021-06-02 10:06:41.466 JupyterHub app:2362] Using Proxy: jupyterhub.proxy.ConfigurableHTTPProxy-1.2.2 E
2021-06-02T10:06:41.469256528Z [I 2021-06-02 10:06:41.469 JupyterHub app:1457] Writing cookie_secret to /srv/jupyterhub/jupyterhub_cookie_secret E
2021-06-02T10:06:41.494694057Z [I 2021-06-02 10:06:41.494 alembic.runtime.migration migration:155] Context impl SQLiteImpl. E
2021-06-02T10:06:41.495207743Z [I 2021-06-02 10:06:41.494 alembic.runtime.migration migration:158] Will assume non-transactional DDL. E
2021-06-02T10:06:41.520272984Z [I 2021-06-02 10:06:41.519 alembic.runtime.migration migration:517] Running stamp_revision → 4dc2d5a8c53c E
2021-06-02T10:06:41.696420888Z [I 2021-06-02 10:06:41.690 JupyterHub proxy:461] Generating new CONFIGPROXY_AUTH_TOKEN E
2021-06-02T10:06:41.696456030Z [W 2021-06-02 10:06:41.692 JupyterHub app:1687] No admin users, admin interface will be unavailable. E
2021-06-02T10:06:41.696467162Z [W 2021-06-02 10:06:41.692 JupyterHub app:1688] Add any administrative users to c.Authenticator.admin_users in config. E
2021-06-02T10:06:41.696476364Z [I 2021-06-02 10:06:41.692 JupyterHub app:1717] Not using allowed_users. Any authenticated user will be allowed. E
2021-06-02T10:06:41.764431054Z [I 2021-06-02 10:06:41.760 JupyterHub app:2399] Initialized 0 spawners in 0.005 seconds E
2021-06-02T10:06:41.766431671Z [W 2021-06-02 10:06:41.765 JupyterHub proxy:655] Running JupyterHub without SSL. I hope there is SSL termination happening somewhere else… E
2021-06-02T10:06:41.766459045Z [I 2021-06-02 10:06:41.765 JupyterHub proxy:659] Starting proxy @ http://:8080/ E
2021-06-02T10:06:42.795514818Z 10:06:42.790 [ConfigProxy] e[32minfoe[39m: Proxying http://*:8080 to (no default) I
2021-06-02T10:06:42.795544011Z 10:06:42.794 [ConfigProxy] e[32minfoe[39m: Proxy API at http://127.0.0.1:8005/api/routes I
2021-06-02T10:06:42.848453299Z 10:06:42.847 [ConfigProxy] e[32minfoe[39m: 200 GET /api/routes I
2021-06-02T10:06:42.849027936Z [I 2021-06-02 10:06:42.848 JupyterHub app:2647] Hub API listening on http://0.0.0.0:8081/hub/ E
2021-06-02T10:06:42.849067692Z [I 2021-06-02 10:06:42.848 JupyterHub app:2649] Private Hub API connect url http://10.56.0.13:8081/hub/ E
2021-06-02T10:06:42.852807313Z 10:06:42.852 [ConfigProxy] e[32minfoe[39m: 200 GET /api/routes I
2021-06-02T10:06:42.853384703Z [I 2021-06-02 10:06:42.853 JupyterHub proxy:320] Checking routes E
2021-06-02T10:06:42.853536476Z [I 2021-06-02 10:06:42.853 JupyterHub proxy:400] Adding default route for Hub: / => http://10.56.0.13:8081 E
2021-06-02T10:06:42.857050192Z 10:06:42.856 [ConfigProxy] e[32minfoe[39m: Adding route / → http://10.56.0.13:8081 I
2021-06-02T10:06:42.857766510Z 10:06:42.857 [ConfigProxy] e[32minfoe[39m: Route added / → http://10.56.0.13:8081 I
2021-06-02T10:06:42.858271548Z 10:06:42.858 [ConfigProxy] e[32minfoe[39m: 201 POST /api/routes/ I
2021-06-02T10:06:42.860752421Z [I 2021-06-02 10:06:42.859 JupyterHub app:2722] JupyterHub is now running at http://:8080/ E
2021-06-02T10:11:36.698005265Z [I 2021-06-02 10:11:36.697 JupyterHub log:181] 302 GET / → /hub/ (@::ffff:10.56.0.14) 1.24ms E
2021-06-02T10:11:36.961851801Z [I 2021-06-02 10:11:36.961 JupyterHub log:181] 302 GET /hub/ → /hub/login?next=%2Fhub%2F (@::ffff:10.56.0.14) 0.84ms E
2021-06-02T10:11:37.224288918Z [I 2021-06-02 10:11:37.223 JupyterHub gcpproxiesauthenticator:64] user_email is phani111@gmail.com E
2021-06-02T10:11:37.247973936Z [I 2021-06-02 10:11:37.247 JupyterHub gcpproxiesauthenticator:109] username is phani111@gmail.com E
2021-06-02T10:11:37.248073429Z [I 2021-06-02 10:11:37.247 JupyterHub gcpproxiesauthenticator:110] user.name is phani111@gmail.com E
2021-06-02T10:11:37.306125736Z [I 2021-06-02 10:11:37.305 JupyterHub reflector:271] watching for pods with label selector=‘component=singleuser-server’ in namespace default E
2021-06-02T10:11:37.319422003Z [I 2021-06-02 10:11:37.319 JupyterHub reflector:271] watching for events with field selector=‘involvedObject.kind=Pod’ in namespace default E
2021-06-02T10:11:37.326054796Z [I 2021-06-02 10:11:37.325 JupyterHub log:181] 200 GET /hub/login?next=%2Fhub%2F (@::ffff:10.56.0.14) 102.76ms E
2021-06-02T10:11:38.661888708Z [I 2021-06-02 10:11:38.661 JupyterHub log:181] 302 GET /hub/ → /hub/spawn (phani111@gmail.com@::ffff:10.56.0.14) 10.97ms E
2021-06-02T10:11:38.922734475Z [I 2021-06-02 10:11:38.922 JupyterHub log:181] 200 GET /hub/spawn (phani111@gmail.com@::ffff:10.56.0.14) 10.46ms E
2021-06-02T10:11:42.863160490Z 10:11:42.862 [ConfigProxy] e[32minfoe[39m: 200 GET /api/routes I
2021-06-02T10:11:42.864090929Z [I 2021-06-02 10:11:42.863 JupyterHub proxy:320] Checking routes E
2021-06-02T10:11:43.150114686Z [E 2021-06-02 10:11:43.149 JupyterHub user:690] Unhandled error starting phani111@gmail.com’s server: No such profile: [‘gcr-io-noted-amphora-248618-jupyter-mine-basic’]. Options include: gcr-io-noted-amphora-248618-jupyter-mine-basic, gcr-io-noted-amphora-248618-jupyter-mine-basic E
2021-06-02T10:11:43.192499074Z [E 2021-06-02 10:11:43.191 JupyterHub pages:261] Failed to spawn single-user server with form E
2021-06-02T10:11:43.192554817Z Traceback (most recent call last): E
2021-06-02T10:11:43.192568481Z File “/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/jupyterhub/handlers/pages.py”, line 257, in post E
2021-06-02T10:11:43.192577262Z return await self._wrap_spawn_single_user( E
2021-06-02T10:11:43.192588011Z File “/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/jupyterhub/handlers/pages.py”, line 314, in _wrap_spawn_single_user E
2021-06-02T10:11:43.192596671Z raise web.HTTPError( E
2021-06-02T10:11:43.192603972Z tornado.web.HTTPError: HTTP 500: Internal Server Error (Error in Authenticator.pre_spawn_start: ValueError No such profile: [‘gcr-io-noted-amphora-248618-jupyter-mine-basic’]. Options include: gcr-io-noted-amphora-248618-jupyter-mine-basic, gcr-io-noted-amphora-248618-jupyter-mine-basic) E
2021-06-02T10:11:43.192613428Z E
2021-06-02T10:11:43.193734621Z [I 2021-06-02 10:11:43.193 JupyterHub log:181] 200 POST /hub/spawn (phani111@gmail.com@::ffff:10.56.0.14) 96.59ms E
2021-06-02T10:11:48.350476518Z [E 2021-06-02 10:11:48.347 JupyterHub user:690] Unhandled error starting phani111@gmail.com’s server: No such profile: [‘gcr-io-noted-amphora-248618-jupyter-mine-basic’]. Options include: gcr-io-noted-amphora-248618-jupyter-mine-basic, gcr-io-noted-amphora-248618-jupyter-mine-basic E
2021-06-02T10:11:48.373694792Z [E 2021-06-02 10:11:48.373 JupyterHub pages:261] Failed to spawn single-user server with form E
2021-06-02T10:11:48.373797482Z Traceback (most recent call last): E
2021-06-02T10:11:48.373814126Z File “/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/jupyterhub/handlers/pages.py”, line 257, in post E
2021-06-02T10:11:48.373821806Z return await self._wrap_spawn_single_user( E
2021-06-02T10:11:48.373829752Z File “/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/jupyterhub/handlers/pages.py”, line 314, in _wrap_spawn_single_user E
2021-06-02T10:11:48.373837262Z raise web.HTTPError( E
2021-06-02T10:11:48.373844504Z tornado.web.HTTPError: HTTP 500: Internal Server Error (Error in Authenticator.pre_spawn_start: ValueError No such profile: [‘gcr-io-noted-amphora-248618-jupyter-mine-basic’]. Options include: gcr-io-noted-amphora-248618-jupyter-mine-basic, gcr-io-noted-amphora-248618-jupyter-mine-basic) E
2021-06-02T10:11:48.373866321Z E
2021-06-02T10:11:48.375421105Z [I 2021-06-02 10:11:48.374 JupyterHub log:181] 200 POST /hub/spawn (phani111@gmail.com@::ffff:10.56.0.14) 76.97ms E
```

please do let me know how to debug this further.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems related to Kubespawner 1.0.0 version. When set to the previous one 0.16.1, it seems to work. Please try pulling the latest code from ai-notebook-extended where kubespawner version is set as a quick fix.

See: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/ai-notebooks-extended/issues/12

Answer (score 0):

Here are some troubleshooting steps to help you fix this issue:

1- It seems that though the installation has messed up somehow, you may try running:

```
pip3 install --upgrade --force-reinstall --no-cache-dir jupyter
```

This should reinstall everything from PyPi.

2-Manually create the docker network first by following the below command

```
user@DOCKER-HOST$ docker create jupyterhub-backend
```

Check that your docker network either exists and/or is being created correctly.

3- Reset your configuration file:

try command

```
jupyter notebook --allow-root
```

(Remember to give space after notebook)

4- Your path  should be:-
/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/opt/aws/bin

5- Try reinstalling jupyter-notebook:-

```
sudo apt install jupyter-notebook
```

After finishing installing then run the command.